# Create T-SQL Constraint to prevent x amount of duplicate records in table?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005, t-sql, constraints, database-relations

In `table A` I have 2 columns:

```
ID (int, PK)
MaxUsers (int)
```

In `table B` I have 2 columns:

```
ItemID (int)
UserID (int)
```

The number of records in `table A` with matching `ItemID`'s cannot exceed the `MaxUsers` value.

Is it possible to write a T-SQL Table Constraint so that it's not physically possible for this to ever happen?

Cheers!
Curt

Comment: What is it that you're trying to solve here? A company that exceeds the number of users it has licenses for or something?

Comment: what would you do then if someone updated the MaxUsers number to a lower limit? Which records in table B would you remove?

Comment: @Lasse - It's something similar to this yes, thanks.

Comment: @Peter - If the MaxUsers value was lowered this would break the constraint, and therefore throw up an exception.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could write an on-insert/update trigger that does a rollback of the query when the conditions are no longer met.

Comment: this sound very good. You'll need both INSERT trigger on table B and UPDATE trigger on table A

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with 'vanilla' constraints e.g. row-level `CHECK` constraints, `UNIQUE` constraints, `FOREIGN KEYS`, making it highly portable e.g.

```
CREATE TABLE TableA 
(
 ID INTEGER NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
 MaxUsers INTEGER NOT NULL CHECK (MaxUsers > 0), 
 UNIQUE (ID, MaxUsers)
);

CREATE TABLE TableB
(
 ID INTEGER NOT NULL,
 MaxUsers INTEGER NOT NULL, 
 FOREIGN KEY (ID, MaxUsers) 
    REFERENCES TableA (ID, MaxUsers), 
 ID_occurrence INTEGER NOT NULL, 
 CHECK (ID_occurrence BETWEEN 1 AND MaxUsers), 
 UNIQUE (ID, ID_occurrence)
);
```

To maintain the `ID_occurrence` sequence, you could create a 'helper' stored proc or a trigger.